# create-with-container doesn't seem to start the container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-os

I am creating a compute engine with a container and I was expecting the compute engine to start the container once it launches. But it doesn't look like the container starts at all. Does create-with-container merely creates a compute engine with a container? If so, how do I tell it to start the container?

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container instance-1 \
  --container-image=us.gcr.io/foo/bar \
  --zone=us-central1-c \
  --machine-type="e2-micro" \
  --scopes=storage-rw,compute-rw
```

EDIT: Your container should start when your VM starts. When passing --container-arg, use equal sign not space. e.g. `--container-arg="--job_id=1"` not `--container-arg="--job_id 1"`

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to use Cloud Run if you just want to "run a container"?

Comment: actually i want to run multiple jobs with different parameters but i couldn't find a way to pass arguments to cloud run job. also my job might run longer than what cloud run permits

Comment: Okay, so how are you currently passing those parameters? For example, do you need `--container-command` or `--container-env`? More importantly, are there logs in Logging service for why the container/instance didn't start?

Comment: The command starts the container. Review the VM instance logs for problems. The VM size might be too small for Docker and the container. Based on your comments regarding arguments, I think you should select Compute Engine and manually set up Docker, your container, etc. Container Optimized OS is designed for locked down (secure) setups.

Comment: @OneCricketeer without passing arguments it starts now. i am not sure what change i made in the container that fixed the problem... when i start a vm with --container-arg="--job_id 1", my container doesn't seem to start. regarding logging, are you talking about logs explorer? i only see 5 notices and nothing more.

Comment: The instance logs... Regard "running multiple jobs", [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/what-cloud-composer) will allow you to better chain multiple events

Comment: So it seems that possibly `--job_id 1` it's breaking the container start up. @OneCricketeer Composer can be okay but possibly it's too expensive depending on the approach of the OP since it deploys a GKE, Cloud SQL and others in addition that it doesn't run containers

Comment: @FerreginaPelona yeah `--container-arg="--job_id 1"` is the problem. with `--container-arg="--job_id=1"` it is running fine now. thank you all!

Comment: @DokookChoe Seems like your issue has been resolved. Can you please post the resolution steps you had done as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 1):

In my case using space instead of equal sign inside the `--container-arg` made my container not start correctly.

Do `--container-arg="--job_id=1"` not `--container-arg="--job_id 1"`

My gcloud command:

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container instance-1 \
  --container-image=us.gcr.io/foo/bar \
  --container-arg="--job_id=1"
```

My container runs fine with both equal sign (`docker run us.gcr.io/foo/bar --job_id=1`) and space (`docker run us.gcr.io/foo/bar --job_id 1`) on my local machine and I am used to using space.